# problem running league of legends

Tags: playonlinux

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and recently installed league of legends. I successfully installed it, but when I started one of the matches, I couldn't see my character or the surrounding terrain. I could see my HUD, so that leads me to believe there is a missing software package.

I installed it using PlayOnLinux. Any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure wine from playonlinux, go to settings+Wine+configure wine+ change windows version to windows 7

Answer (score 0):

From the Official Wine page:

It's important to remember that if you're running on a 64-bit environment like I am, that the wine build you use for LoL is only 32-bit: if your distro offers a multilib version of wine, you need to make sure it only compiles 32-bit binaries and libs, otherwise LoL won't work right, or the game will go completely black after champion selection so that the only thing that you can see is the mouse cursor.